# Expression équivalente à « mutton dressed as lamb » ?

Tags: expressions

C'est une expression un peu cruelle, mais de nos jours j'estime que cela peut s'appliquer aux deux sexes. Chez les francophones, avec ce sens de jugement sévère concernant style et fringues de quelqu'un, une locution équivalente doit exister.
[Sens de l'expression en anglais.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mutton-dressed-as-lamb.html)

Comment: Des explications sur le sens de l’expression seraient fort utiles.

Comment: Pardon, l'expression se traduit par "viande de mouton mûr présentée comme de l'agneau".  "Dressed" est "habillé", mais l'expression comporte un jeu de mots, car on parle aussi de "to dress" (verbe = "présenter") tel ou tel plat.  Donc cela veut dire, dans un sens plutôt large, une personne (homme ou femme mais le plus souvent des femmes) qui adopte les vêtements, mais aussi les manières, attitudes, etc., de gens sensiblement moins âgés qu'elle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comme @Laure, je ne vois pas vraiment d'équivalent.

En langage familier, on dirait :

> Elle s'habille comme une ado / une midinette
>
> Elle veut faire sa jeunette
>
> Elle (il) s'habille comme sa fille (son fils)

On peut aussi jouer sur les oxymores comme "une Lolita défraichie", "un vieux beau", "un ado de 40 ans", etc.

Comment: J’aime la midinette.

Comment: Les oxymores sont intéressants

Comment: Une midinette implique des valeurs « morales » (naïveté et frivolité) qui ne sont pas du tout contenue dans l'expression anglaise, laquelle n'est pas une expression familière.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas d'expression aussi imagée en français. On exprimera l'idée de diverses façons selon le contexte.

Sans connotation péjorative on peut dire :

- Il s'habille trop jeune pour son âge.
- Il veut paraître plus jeune que son âge.
- Elle cherche à cacher ses cheveux gris.

Si on veut garder la connotation péjorative contenue dans *mutton dressed as lamb* il y a des expressions qui, à mon avis, n'ont pas tout à fait le même sens :

- « [avoir l'air d'un vieux tableau](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=10978) » : très vieilli, signifiant qu'on mettait de la peinture (maquillage) pour masquer ce qu'il y a en-dessous.
- « [avoir l'air d'un vieux beau](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=35108) » est encore, mais peu fréquent quand même. Implique qu'on cherche à faire plus jeune qu'on est dans le but de séduire.
  Je ne l'ai jamais entendu employé pour une femme (qui serait « avoir l'air d'une vieille belle », bien sûr).

Comment: Je n'ai pas non plus entendu *vieille belle*, mais vous pourriez ajouter, dans un style plus familier quelque chose comme :  *Tu as piqué les fringues de ta fille ?*

Comment: @cl-r: j'ai exclu toute expression familière car ce serait trahir encore plus l'expression anglaise qui n'est pas du tout familière et ressentie même comme littéraire.

Answer (score 2):

Une expression francophone qui se rapproche serait: « à vieille mule, frein doré ».

Cela ne concerne pas particulièrement l'habillement mais l'idée est similaire.

[Wikitionaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_vieille_mule,_frein_dor%C3%A9) nous donne cette définition:

> On garnit une vieille bête pour pouvoir mieux la vendre, se dit aussi des vieilles femmes qui abusent des produits de toilette.

Comment: Tres belle comme expression !

Answer (score 0):

Au Québec on dit *habillé(e) comme la chienne à Jacques*.

Comment: Après quelques recherches, il semblerait que « mutton dressed as a lamb » signifie s’habiller comme une personne (bien) plus jeune, alors qu’être « habillé comme la chienne à Jacques » signifie essentiellement être mal habillé.